# Including Fortran libraries in a CMake file for .cxx project

Tags: makefile, cmake, fortran

I'm using the PSOPT package (http://www.psopt.org/) on my research. Instead of using the Makefile that comes within the package, I'm trying to create my own makefile using CMake.

In the default Makefile some Fortran object files are called, more specifically,

```
FLIBS        =  -lm -lf2c  -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas
```

How can I insert and link these Fortran libraries in my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I doubt you want `libf2c` today. Or do they distribute pre-processed `.c` files? Note the download page on http://www.psopt.org/ leads to a discontinued Google code page.

Comment: Have you read any CMake tutorial to begin with? Linking with libraries is performed via [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: You can download the psopt packat at:  https://github.com/PSOPT/psopt/blob/master/install-ubuntu.sh

Comment: Yes, I've read some tutorials. The other libraries (dmatrix, psopt, lusol etc) have already been linked, these fortran and C libraries I was not able to link.